# What are the available hooks for views

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I cannot find the list in the api documentation.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_hooks/8.5.x

Nor am I able to enter such functions in a theme when loading a page with a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're here

- In the codebase: core/modules/views/views.api.php.
- On the web: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/8.5.x

As always, only `*_alter` hooks and `hook_theme` can be implemented in a theme. Any other hook needs to be implemented in a module.